# Use value from dropdown to set setInterval with jQuery change

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, setinterval

I'm trying to have a dropdown menu that let the user to select how often the page should refresh.  I have the following code in $(document).ready( ) :

```
$(".refreshInterval").change( setInterval( showDashboard(),parseFloat( $(".refreshInterval").val() )*60*1000) );
```

...where refreshInterval is...

```
<select class="refreshInterval" value="1">
    <option value="0">Off</option>
    <option value="0.5" selected>30 sec</option>
    <option value="1">1 min</option>
    <option value="2">2 min</option>
    <option value="5">5 min</option>
</select>
```

And `showDashboard()` is an accessible function.  On initial loading of the page, `showDashboard()` is called.  However, when I changed the drop down menu, I get this error from **jQuery**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 166 has no method 'apply'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you write your code in a more clear fashion (instead of doing one-liners). It's easier to spot syntax errors this way.

Solution: (**not good, check edit!**)

```
$(".refreshInterval").change(function() {    
    var interval = parseFloat( $(this).val() ) * 60 * 1000;
    setInterval(showDashboard(), interval) 
});
​
```

You were missing

```
 function() { }
```

**EDIT --------**

Sorry ! I put

```
setInterval(showDashboard(), interval)
```

It should have been

```
setInterval(showDashboard, interval);
```

Here is the correct full code:

```
 ref = setInterval(showDashboard, 1000) 

$(".refreshInterval").change(function() {    
    var interval = parseFloat( $(this).val() ) * 60 * 1000;
    clearInterval(ref);
    console.log("New Interval: " + interval);
    if (interval > 0) {
        ref = setInterval(showDashboard, interval)     
    }
});


function showDashboard() {
    console.log(Math.random());
}

​
```

And the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xkj43/3/

Comment: That sort of works.  How do I make it so it will fire once on load and then listens for the change?

Comment: @PLui Just put a `showDashboard()` call higher up in your doc ready function.

Comment: This refreshes when and only when the dropdown box is changed.  It doesn't seem to refresh regularly.  I added a console.log in showDashboard to confirm it.

Comment: @PLui, I edited it and wrote the full code including the refresh. Please verify.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".refreshInterval").change(function(){

setInterval(showDashboard,parseFloat($(".refreshInterval").val())*60*1000)

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function to the event.. You are passing a method here.

Also change this `showDashboard()`   to `showDashboard`
 Try this

```
$(".refreshInterval").change(function(){    
      setInterval(showDashboard,parseFloat($(".refreshInterval").val())*60*1000))
  });
```

Comment: When I had `showDashboard()` instead of `showDashboard`, `setInterval` calls it.  But without the `()`, it doesn't call it at all.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers that point out you need to pass a function to `setInterval` are correct.

However, you're setting a new interval every change call without clearing out the old one, so if someone selects "1" and then "5", you will get 6 calls to `showDashboard` every 5 minutes. You need to capture the interval id and clear it before each new `setInterval` call.

```
$(function() {
    var dashboardRefreshInterval;
    $(".refreshInterval").change(function(){
           clearInterval(dashboardRefreshInterval);
           dashboardRefreshInterval = setInterval(showDashboard,parseFloat($(".refreshInterval").val())*60*1000))   
     }); 
}
```

Comment: That's a good point.  But similar to @aktee's solution, this refreshes when and only when the dropdown box is changed. It doesn't seem to refresh regularly. I added a console.log in showDashboard to confirm it.

Comment: No, this will refresh at the selected interval and correctly change the interval when the dropdown selection is changed. Do you mean it does not start refreshing at intervals until the first time the user makes a selection?